# Logstash - grok use a field other than message

Tags: log4j, logstash

I am receiving Log4j generated log files from remote servers using Logstash forwarder. The log event has fields including a field named "file" in the format /tomcat/logs/app.log, /tomcat/logs/app.log.1, etc. Of course file path /tomcat/logs is on the remote machine and I would like Logstash to create files on the local file system using only the file name and not use the remote file path.

Locally, I would like to create a file based on file name app.log, app.log.1, etc. How can one accomplish this?

I am unable to use grok since it appears to work only with "message" field and not others.

Example Log Event:

{"message":["11 Sep 2014 16:29:04,934 INFO LOG MESSAGE DETAILS HERE "],"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2014-09-15T05:44:43.472Z","file":["/tomcat/logs/app.log.1"],"host":"aus-002157","offset":"3116","type":"app.log"}

Logstash configuration  - what do I use to write the filter section?

```
input {
    lumberjack {
      port => 48080
      ssl_certificate => "/tools/LogStash/logstash-1.4.2/ssl/logstash.crt"
      ssl_key => "/tools/LogStash/logstash-1.4.2/ssl/logstash.key"
    }
}

filter{

}

output {

    file{
        #message_format => "%{message}"
        flush_interval => 0
        path => "/tmp/%{host}.%{type}.%{filename}"
        max_size => "4M"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash [Grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok#match) can parse all the fields in a log event, not only `message` field.

For example, you want to extract the `file` field,
you can do like this

```
filter {
   grok {
       match => [ "file", "your pattern" ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What would be the pattern for extracting file name app.log.1 ?

Comment: How would you access a child in file? E.g. `{"file": {"name": "foobar.log"}}`

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the pattern to be as follows:

```
grok{
    match => [ "file",  "^(/.*/)(?<filename>(.*))$" ]
}
```

Thanks for the help!